# How to sort column order by column name with dates

Tags: python, pandas, sorting

I have a dataframe such as:

| data | more data | 2010-01-01 | 2011-01-01 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | xyz | 123 | 456 |
| xyz | abc | 123 | 456 |

and I would like to sort the columns in a certain order. I tried using sort_values and passing a list with the order I want them in but it is not recognizing '2010-01-01' or any other dates in the list. I assume it is because they are in date format, so how would I sort these labels?

What I currently am trying:

```
order = ['more data', 'data', '2011-01-01', '2010-01-01']
df = df.sort_values(order)
```

Comment: Post your code, even if it didn't work.

Comment: post your data in json or dictionaery

Comment: what specific order would you like?

Comment: @mozway I want to be able to use a list with them in a written order

Comment: `df[pd.to_datetime(df.columns,errors='ignore').sort_values(ascending=False)]` ?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want, by try: `df = df.reindex(order, axis=1)`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not pretty sure how you want to handle non-datetime columns. I assume that you prefer these columns to show at the beginning of the dataframe. With that in mind, I suggest you use `sorted` function:

```py
import time
import datetime
def sort_date(value):
  try:
    return -1 * time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime(value, "%Y-%m-%d").timetuple())
  except:
    return float("-inf")
columns = ['data', '2011-01-01', "value", '2010-01-01']

sorted(columns, key=sort_date)
```

The abovementioned code has nothing to do with `pandas` dataframe - rather, gives you a better idea of how to handle such a situation. The `sorted` function mentioned returns the following output:

```
['data', 'value', '2011-01-01', '2010-01-01']
```

Therefore, you can simply use the returned value of the abovementioned code to sort your columns out:

```py
df[sorted(columns, key=sort_date)]
```

Note that you can access the columns of the dataframe by simply using `df.columns`.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to re-sort the date columns and not any of the others you have to write a bit more code. Something like:

```
# Separate date columns from non-date columns
non_date_cols = ['name']
date_cols = [col for col in df.columns if col not in non_date_cols] # Get a list of the date column names

# Sort the column names (not the actual columns)
date_cols.sort()

# Rebuild your dataframe by taking the non date cols and joining the rest of the columns in the order specified
df_sorted = df[non_date_cols + date_cols]
```